# Re.match does not restrict urls

Tags: python, regex

I would like to get only those school URLs in the table on this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_districts_in_Alabama) that lead to a page with information.  The bad urls are colored red contain the phrase 'page does not exist' in side the 'title' attr. I am trying to use re.match() to filter the URLs such that I only return those which do not contain the aforementioned string. Why isn't re.match() working?

URL:

```
districts_page = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_school_districts_in_Alabama'
```

FUNCTION:

```
def url_check(url):

    all_urls = []

    r = requests.get(url, proxies = proxies)
    html_source = r.text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)

    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        if type(link.get('title')) == str:
            if re.match(link.get('title'), '(page does not exist)') == None: 
                all_urls.append(link.get('href'))
            else: pass

    return
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not address fixing the problem with `re.match`, but may be a valid approach for you without using regex:

```
  for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    title = link.get('title')
    if title:
      if not 'page does not exist' in title: 
        all_urls.append(link.get('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

The order of the arguments to `re.match` should be the pattern then the string. So try:

```
    if not re.search(r'(page does not exist)', link.get('title')):
```

(I've also changed `re.match` to `re.search` since -- as @goldisfine observed -- the pattern does not occur at the beginning of the string.)

---

Using @kindall's observation, your code could also be simplified to

```
for link in soup.find_all('a', 
        title=lambda x: x is not None and 'page does not exist' not in x):
    all_urls.append(link.get('href'))
```

This eliminates the two `if-statements`. It can all be incorporated into the call to `soup.find_all`.

Comment: There's no reason to even use a regex to begin with since no pattern-matching features are being used. Also, the parens have special meaning in a regex and should be escaped (or omitted entirely, I doubt that would cause any problems here).

Answer (score 0):

Unutbu's answer addresses the syntax error. But simply using re.match() is not enough. Re.match looks at the beginning of the string. `re.search()` goes through the entire string until it happens upon a section of the string that matches the entered pattern.

The following code works:

```
for link in soup.find_all('a'):
    if type(link.get('title')) == str:
        if re.search('page does not exist',link.get('title')) == None: 
            all_urls.append(link.get('href'))
return all_urls
```